# Parse whereKey doesNotMatchKey inQuery returns objects that match the key

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've got a class that tracks if a user has seen an object before. If so then I add a row saying USER has seen OBJECT. Now I have a query to grab a new list of objects and I don't want the user to see objects they have already seen.

I have a very complicated query for grabbing the new list of objects but the part where I look for objects the user hasn't seen before is pasted below:

```
// Query the object class
PFQuery *haventSeenBeforeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:ObjectSeenClass];
// Find all objects that the logged in user has seen
[haventSeenBeforeQuery whereKey:UserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// Make sure the query does not return objects the user has already seen
[query whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:UserIDStringKey inQuery:haventSeenBeforeQuery];
```

I followed the advice here: https://parse.com/questions/trouble-with-nested-query-using-objectid. And added an extra column in my User class that contains a string of the user's objectId.

Most of the time this works perfectly, but I have small subset of users who are seeing objects they've already seen over and over and over. I checked and the ObjectSeen rows are being added to Parse, so I think Parse is returning me objects I've told it I don't want to see.

Comment: How many objects are there? Are you overflowing the maximum number of return items?

Comment: There are lots of objects. But I only grab 10 at a time (query.limit = 10) so I shouldn't be overflowing the return items. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm thinking there might be a limit on the nested query, hence it misses only some of the seen items (and always the same ones)

Comment: Shoot you may be right. Do you know what the limit is? I've heard 1000 objects but I know for sure that the users seeing the same items haven't seen 1000 objects yet. And is there any way to get around this issue if it is a limiting issue?

Comment: I think 1000is the max but 100 is then default IIRC

Comment: Okay cool I think you solved it for me, thanks man! You can answer it below and I'll mark it correct for you if you want